# convert yyyymmdd to serial number python

Tags: python, datetime

How do I convert a list of dates that are in the form yyyymmdd to a serial number? For example, if I have this list of dates:

```
t = [1898-10-12 06:00,1898-10-12 12:00,1932-09-30 08:00,1932-09-30 00:00]
```

How do I convert each date to a serial number? Im currently using the datetime toordinal() command, but each date is being rounded to the same serial number. How do I get the same dates with different times to be different numbers?

The times in the list are the datetime.datetime numbers. I tried then doing:

```
thurser = []
for i in range(len(t)):
    thurser.append(t[i].toordinal())
```

But am not getting serial numbers as floats.

Comment: Is that a list of strings or a list of `datedime.datetime`?

Comment: It is a list of datetime.datetime

Comment: what do you mean by serial number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`datetime.toordinal()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.toordinal) considers only the 'date' part of the datetime object, not the time. So does [`date.toordinal()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.toordinal) - it only has a date part. The first 2 and last 2 elements in your list have datetimes on the same date but at different times, which `.toordinal` ignores. So, `.toordinal` will give you the same value for those same-dated datetimes.

In general, the solution would be to calculate the delta between your dates and a pre-determined/fixed one. I'm using `datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1)`, the earliest possible datetime, so all the deltas are positive:

```
thurser = []
# assuming t is a list of datetime objects
for d in t:
    delta = d - datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1)
    thurser.append(delta.days + delta.seconds/(24 * 3600))

>>> print(thurser)
[693149.25, 693149.5, 705555.3333333334, 705555.0]
```

And if you prefer ints instead of floats, then use seconds instead of days:

```
thurser.append(int(delta.total_seconds()))  # total_seconds has microseconds in the float

>>> print(thurser)
[59888095200, 59888116800, 60959980800, 60959952000]
```

And to get back the original values in the 2nd example:

```
>>> [datetime.timedelta(seconds=d) + datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1) for d in thurser]
[datetime.datetime(1898, 10, 12, 6, 0), datetime.datetime(1898, 10, 12, 12, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1932, 9, 30, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(1932, 9, 30, 0, 0)]
>>> _ == t  # compare with original values
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if my understanding is wrong, I tried following and gives distinct numbers for each value of the list.
I modified
`t = ['1898-10-12 06:00','1898-10-12 12:00','1932-09-30 08:00','1932-09-30 00:00']`
 with
`t = [datetime.datetime(1898, 10, 12, 6, 0), datetime.datetime(1898, 10, 12, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(1932, 9, 30, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(1932, 9, 30, 0, 0)]`
As mentioned in comment it is list of datetime.datetime.
I am considering total MilliSeconds from `1970-01-01 00:00:00` the given date to generate a number.
So dates which are before above date give values in negative. But distinct values.

```
t = [datetime.datetime(1898, 10, 12, 6, 0), datetime.datetime(1898, 10, 12, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(1932, 9, 30, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(1932, 9, 30, 0, 0)]
thurser = []
x = []
for i in range(len(t)):
    thurser.append(t[i].toordinal())
    x.append((t[i]-datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds() * 1000.0)

print(thurser)
print(x)
```

output:

> ```
> [693150, 693150, 705556, 705556]
> [-2247501600000.0, -2247480000000.0, -1175616000000.0, -1175644800000.0]
> ```